# How to dynamically import Material Design and MDI icons?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
import CargoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Storage';
import BargeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DirectionsBoat';
import VesselIcon from '@material-ui/icons/DirectionsBoat';
import CompanyIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Business';
import { mdiMapMarkerRadius, mdiFileChart, mdiFileSearch, mdiShipWheel } from '@mdi/js';

const subscriptions = [
  {
    id: 'POSITION',
    name: 'SMART Position',
    icon: <SvgIcon><path d={mdiMapMarkerRadius} /></SvgIcon>,
    path: '/app/module/smart-position',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-position/'
  },
  {
    id: 'CARGO',
    name: 'SMART Cargo',
    icon: <CargoIcon />,
    path: '/app/module/smart-cargo',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-cargo/'
  },
  {
    id: 'ANALYTICS',
    name: 'SMART Analytics',
    icon: <SvgIcon><path d={mdiFileChart} /></SvgIcon>,
    path: '/app/module/smart-analytics',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-analytics/'
  },
  {
    id: 'INSPECTOR',
    name: 'SMART Inspector',
    icon: <SvgIcon><path d={mdiFileSearch} /></SvgIcon>,
    path: '/app/module/smart-inspector',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-inspector/'
  },
  {
    id: 'BARGE',
    name: 'SMART Barge',
    icon: <BargeIcon />,
    path: '/app/module/smart-barge',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-barge/'
  },
  {
    id: 'COMPANY',
    name: 'SMART Company',
    icon: <CompanyIcon />,
    path: '/app/module/smart-Company',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-company/'
  },
  {
    id: 'VESSEL',
    name: 'SMART Vessel',
    icon: <VesselIcon />,
    path: '/app/module/smart-vessel',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-vessel/'
  },
  {
    id: 'LOCATION',
    name: 'SMART Location',
    icon: <SvgIcon><path d={mdiMapMarkerRadius} /></SvgIcon>,
    path: '/app/module/smart-location',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-location/'
  },
  {
    id: 'FLEET',
    name: 'SMART Fleet',
    icon: <SvgIcon><path d={mdiShipWheel} /></SvgIcon>,
    path: '/app/module/fleet',
    link: 'https://oceansmart.com/smart-fleet/'
  },
]

export default subscriptions;
```

What I want to be able to do is instead of passing the `icon: icon with wrapper` I want to be able to do `icon: icon_name`. Whats the best way I can do this?

This is because I do not want to pass an icon inside the constant file I have and would rather have just the name and create the name dynamically in another file.

I am not sure the best way to do this as one is in mdi prefix and Material UI brings it in with its name so I am a bit confused on the best way to do this.

Comment: Does this fit your demand?https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/utils/createSvgIcon.js

Comment: How would I use this?
`import { createSvgIcon } from '@material-ui/core/utils';`
`Attempted import error: 'createSvgIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/utils'.`
I get an error trying to import it.